# How Can I Estimate the Full Path Route of an Aircraft From a Given Halft Path?

Tags: machine-learning, python, deep-learning

I have a lot of real data of aircrafts paths which starts from the departure airport and ends on the arrival airport. Each aircrafts data is a time series of points like below:

Point(lat, lon, elevation, timeMs) // the point includes coordinates in X seccond

```
Data for Aircraft_X1 path
27.1, 10.7, 9500, 1641859205
27.2  10.6  9500, 1641859210
27.3  10.5  9400, 1641859215
....
```

The time differs 5 seccond in between of each sequential point and there may be 1000+ points for just one aircrafts path.

I want to make predictions for that paths, so when I give the first half of the path of an aircraft, the algorithm must return me the estimated full path which the aircraft will follow. How can I do that? I though the Seq2Seq model can be useful but the data shape is not helpful, because they are time series of points.

I want to use deep learning or machine learning. I don't want to make it with reinforcement learning, I already have the real data.